# How is my rails nested model data being saved with no id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, post, resources

I have a nested resource:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :cust_uploads
  end
```

After uploads are made, I can view a list of them under the users index page:

```
  <% @user.cust_uploads.each do |up| %>
     <li><%= up.name %></li>
  <% end %>
```

But when I go to: /users/3/cust_uploads/1 I get a record not found error: Couldn't find CustUpload with id=1.  Am I not saving to DB properly?

Any idea whats happening or how I can diagnose?

schema has no ID columns but I thought that was automatic?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130109001001) do

  create_table "cust_uploads", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "cust_file_url"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe 1 is not the ID of the created model. Try printing them like this and then click on a model:

```
<% @user.cust_uploads.each do |up| %>
   <li><%= link_to up.name, up %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Always the easy solution when digging in deep!  Thanks